# Copy .txt file onto a separate .txt file - python

Tags: python

Hello this question will probably be rather straight forward.

I have a `.txt` file, lets stay `fruits.txt` , In the code when each fruit is randomly selected it is removed from the `.txt` file so it is not used again.

However when the selection process or "quiz" is ran again, obviously all of the fruits in `fruits.txt` have been deleted.

I was wondering if there is such code that will allow for another `.txt` file, such as `fruitsoriginal.txt` to have it's content copied over to `fruits.txt`.

I doubt this will help at all but this is the code that removes a fruit from the list, `a` is a random fruit.

```
 f = open("fruits.txt","r")
 lines = f.readlines()
 f.close()
 f = open("fruits.txt","w")
 for line in lines:
    if line!=a+"\n":
     f.write(line) 
 f.close()
```

Comment: Why are you modifying fruits.txt?

Comment: So that the same fruit is not used again when I ask a question about the fruit.

Comment: Yes, but why are you modifying the file? Isn't it easier to read the contents of fruits.txt into your program, leave the file untouched and update the data in your program (in a list for example)?

Comment: Oh yes, how silly of me. I have all ready programmed the modification of the .txt file and the random selection, so if there's no simple answer regarding copying the data from a different .txt file I will try what you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `copy` from [shutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)

```
import shutil
shutil.copy('fruitsoriginal.txt', 'fruits.txt')
```